# jQuery Gridstack plugin - Get elements attributes, fix resize handle and lock items when others move

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add widgets to a gridstack (dynamically), but facing some problems:

1. I need to get all items ids, position X, position Y, width and height in order to store the grid widgets position. I managed to do it (maybe not the better way), but I'm always getting one more item than expected. This unexpected item has all attributes undefined. How can I get the correct list of widgets and their attributes?

   ```
   $('#b2').on('click', function() {

     var items = '';

     $('.grid-stack-item').each(function() {
       items += 'id: ' + $(this).attr('id') + ';  ';
       items += 'X: ' + $(this).val($(this).attr('data-gs-x')).attr('data-gs-x') + ';  '
       items += 'Y: ' + $(this).val($(this).attr('data-gs-y')).attr('data-gs-y') + ';  '
       items += 'Width: ' + $(this).val($(this).attr('data-gs-width')).attr('data-gs-width') + ';  '
       items += 'Height: ' + $(this).val($(this).attr('data-gs-height')).attr('data-gs-height') + ';  '
       items += '\n';
     });

     alert(items);
   });
   ```
2. When I add a widget, move it to the middle or bottom of the page, then add another widget, the first one moves to the top. How can I prevent that?
3. The resize handle is the wrong way around and cut. How can I fix it?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ca2s7l/9fkn6atm/3/)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `_gridstack_node` data attribute of the node, it keeps internal info for the node (I will add this to README):

```
$('.grid-stack-item').each(function () {
    var node = $(this).data('_gridstack_node');
    if (typeof node == 'undefined')
        return;
    console.log(node);
});
```

The extra item you receive is placeholder for dragging/resizing view. It's hidden until you start to drag/resize.

2. If you're going to add bunch of widgets you need to sort them before. Please see an example https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js#load-grid-from-array
3. Do you include Font Awesome?